# Enable another user to set gmail filter for my email

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

I am looking to set up an email forwarding system. I have successfully used the Gmail API to read and edit emails from my ADMIN account (the admin account is a gmail account that I created and has oauth2 credentials from the Gmail API as described in the [Quickstart guide](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python)).

I would now like to enable USERS of my web application to click a button that will programmatically create an Gmail filter for the USER email that will forward specific messages to the ADMIN email. I am using the Python API.

I am trying to use the filter API, but am getting a "Delegation denied for ADMIN_EMAIL.

How do I approach this?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you set up a Service Account? Also, are you a G Suite User?

Comment: I don’t think I have a service account, is that required here? And by G Suite user, do you mean my “admin” email is a Gmail account?

Comment: Following up, I don't have a service account and my "admin" user is just a regular gmail, not a gsuite account. Do I need a Gsuite account? I would like to be able to authorize my "admin" email to be able to access emails from my users normal gmail accounts

Comment: To clarify, by "normal email accounts", I mean their personal email accounts, not accounts that have a company domain (which from what I can understand is what Gsuite is for)

Comment: I see. In your post I understood "admin"  as a G Suite admin account. Are these users in your domain? Because the "Delegation denied" error is related to [Domain Wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation) which is an exclusive G Suite feature and it's required to access the Gmail of another user. Can you show the code of your webApp?

Comment: I resolved this by changing my approach to enable each user to link their email and set up the correct settings. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Glad you could solve it! Would you like to post the solution as an answer? So others can benefit from the post. Cheers!